# App freezes under IOS6 when using RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache

Tags: objective-c, ios6, restkit

I'm using RestKit in an app developed under IOS5, and everything was working perfectly until I upgraded to IOS6. Now I experience that the app freezes randomly when I fetch data from the server :( I've narrowed it down to only occurring when I use RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache. But if I disable RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache I experience duplicate records.

Have anybody else experiences similar problems under IOS6?

EDIT:
In instruments I can see that it often freezes while executing the fetchrequest in load method of RKEntityByAttributeCache